# Error: expected initializer before '.' token

Tags: c++, class, sdl

I am fairly new to using classes and the Object Oriented side of C++ and get the error in the title.

I am writing a game of Tetris using SDL.

I have a class definition in shapes.h

```
class shape
{
public:
    SDL_Surface *colour;
    int rotation1[4][4];
    int rotation2[4][4];
    int rotation3[4][4];
    int rotation4[4][4];

    bool load();
    void move();

    shape();
};
```

and in main.h i have included shapes.h and defined instances of the class with

```
//Create shapes
shape O, T, S, L, R, Z, I;
```

I also have seperate files for each shape such as I.cpp as each shape will have different code for loading the image for its colour of block onto the SDL_Surface colour and for the various arrays of different rotations of the block, so i seperated this into one file for each block.

In I.cpp I have included main.h and tried to set up the load function for I as follows:

```
bool I.load()
{
    //if loading the cyan square texture fails
    if ((I.colour = surface::onLoad("../Textures/cyanSquare.png")) == NULL)
    {
        //print error
        cout << "Unable to load cyanSquare.png";
        //return fail
        return false;
    }

    I.rotation1 = {{7,7,7,7},
                   {0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0}};
    I.rotation2 = {{0,0,7,0},
                   {0,0,7,0},
                   {0,0,7,0},
                   {0,0,7,0}};
    I.rotation3 = {{7,7,7,7},
                   {0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0}};
    I.rotation4 = {{0,0,7,0},
                   {0,0,7,0},
                   {0,0,7,0},
                   {0,0,7,0}};

    return true;
}
```

When I try to compile this (using GCC) it reports an error on line 3 of I.cpp of:

```
error: expected initializer before '.' token
```

I have absolutely no idea what this means, and could not find anything of use searching google for this error code, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be time to put down the compiler and pick up [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool I.load()
```

shouldn't it be 
`bool shape::load()` ?

I is just an instance of type 'shape'. How can you use 'I' inside the function implementation as it knows nothing about the 'I' instance!

You probably want to do this:
1. Add a construct with parameter to specify the picture for the instance:

```
class shape
{
public:
//....

    shape(const char* pImagePath);
private:
    const char* m_pImagePath;
};
```

and implement the constructor as:

```
shape::shape(const char* image_path) : m_pImagePath(pImagePath) {}
```

Your load() then can be implemented as:

```
bool shape::load()
{
    //if loading the cyan square texture fails
    if ((colour = surface::onLoad(m_pImagePath)) == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Unable to load cyanSquare.png";
        return false;
    }

    rotation1 = {{7,7,7,7},
                 {0,0,0,0},
                 {0,0,0,0},
                 {0,0,0,0}};
    rotation2 = {{0,0,7,0},
                 {0,0,7,0},
                 {0,0,7,0},
                 {0,0,7,0}};
    rotation3 = {{7,7,7,7},
                 {0,0,0,0},
                 {0,0,0,0},
                 {0,0,0,0}};
    rotation4 = {{0,0,7,0},
                 {0,0,7,0},
                 {0,0,7,0},
                 {0,0,7,0}};

    return true;
}
```

Create instance 'I' as following:

```
shape I("../Textures/cyanSquare.png");
```

Comment: I think that would work, is it not therefore possible to specify a different function for each instance of the class, because as you can see they will each have different arrays and a different texture. I am sorry if I sound ridiculous, i have never used classes before.

Comment: I have used your method, and it all appears to work fine other than creating the instance 'I' - i get two errors on this line:
`expected identifier before string constant` and 
`expected ',' or '...' before string constant`

Answer (score 4):

This is not valid C++.  `I` is a variable; you cannot define a member function for a specific variable (`bool I.load()`).  Perhaps you meant `bool shape::load()`?